# Javascript not checking whether a checkbox was selected or not

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox

I'm trying to build a quiz with multiple choice questions, one of which has multiple correct answers. So I'm trying to check which checkboxes in my questions have been selected by a student in order to give the right feedback. my code is:

```
for(var i = 0; i< input1.length; i++)
    {
        if(input1[0].checked && input1[1].checked)
        {
        submit_answer.onclick = showFeedback1; 
        }
        else
        {
        submit_answer.onclick = false1; 
        }
    }
```

It never takes the first if, even if I select those two only. No matter what I put in the if statement, it only takes the else.

and this is just a part of my .js

```
var quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');

var questions = quiz.getElementsByTagName('p');

input1 = questions[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

var submit_answer = document.getElementById('submit_answers'); // this is the submit button
```

Comment: Your code looks strange. Could you make a fiddle so that we see how it's called ?

Comment: You're checking the same two checkboxes each time through the loop, because you don't use `i`.

Comment: Never validate a form in a loop! be specific with the targeted elements when validating.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this script. Read all the answers you've seen so far, and the comments...don't validate in for loops, actually use your i variable if you plan to anyway, and learn about addEventListener and removeEventListener.

Also, we need more context to even begin to decipher what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot make proper assumption of what you are trying to do.

**FIRST PROBLEM**

Your for loop is incrementing on 1, so on the each next iteration it is comparing using same previously used value.

**SECOND PROBLEM**

Your structure is horrible, your script fetches up all the input elements inside every p. You should properly organize your element in groups and then match whether or not they are checked.

Comment: He should use the i variable inside the loop. But shouldn't use a loop here at all anyway.